# Select FROM 3 Table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Well I think it's a simple question but I could not found the solution.

Well I have three Tables:

**Table 1**

```
id(AS t1id)    Name  LASTNAME Value 

1              a     z         50

2              b     e         60 

3              c     k         70

4              d     u         60
```

**Table2**

```
id   idTable1   Name(AS t2me)   Value(AS t2ve)

1     1          er             50

2     1          zx             150

3     2          zc             300
```

**Table 3**

```
id   idTable1   Name(AS t3me)   Value(AS t3ve)

1     2         erxc   50

2     2         zvvx   150

3     2         zcz    300
```

How to get this result with `SQL`

```
t1id    Name      LASTNAME   t2me    t2ve     t3me     t3ve

1       a         z           er      50      erdxc    150

1       a         z           zx      150           

2       b         e           zc      300      erxc    50

2       b         e                            zvvx    150

2       b         e                            zcz     300
```

Is that possible? If not what could I do?

Comment: and what exactly is the problem?  this is a rather standard use case for `left join`s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id as t1id, t1.Name, t1.LASTNAME, 
    t2.Name as t2me, t2.Value as t2ve, t3.Name as t3me, 
    t3.Value as t3ve from Table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.idTable1 
LEFT JOIN Table3 on t3.idTable1 = t1.id
```

Comment: That's is thanks
I Tried right join and inner join but It's does not work 
but I forgot the left
Thank's again